# Moving Down the Background Image in Mobile

Tags: html, css

I want to move the background image lower in `@media screen and (max-width: 660px)` because every time I change the screen size it moves up the background image. What I want is everytime I change to smaller screen size the image will goes down to fill some spaces.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Modak|Poppins|Ubuntu&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/xhgZz0F/bg-image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 13vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  /* background-color:#000; */
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #E73A15;
  top: 30%;
  left: 2%;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 45px;
  /* background-color: black; */
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 18%;
}

.social ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 6px;
  text-align: center;
}

.faceb,
.linked,
.git {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #E73A15;
  text-align: center;
}

.centerIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#menu {
  margin: 2.2rem 3rem 0 0;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: .5rem .8rem;
  margin: 0 .3rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .7rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu .nav a {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav {
  background: rgb(209, 129, 129);
  background: linear-gradient(118deg, rgba(209, 129, 129, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 81, 52, 1) 35%, rgba(231, 58, 21, 1) 100%);
  border-radius: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  body {
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/xhgZz0F/bg-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: auto;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .social {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Jury Gregorio | Design for Everyone</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">Jury</div>
    <div class="social">

      <ul>
        <li class="faceb">
          <div class="centerIcon"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></div></i></li>
        <li class="linked">
          <div class="centerIcon"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></div></i></li>
        <li class="git">
          <div class="centerIcon"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      </div>

      <div id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
background-position: center bottom;
```

you can also add px instead of the words

Play around with the values that fits best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Jury Gregorio | Design for Everyone</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Modak|Poppins|Ubuntu&display=swap');
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/xhgZz0F/bg-image.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    header {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 13vh;
      min-width: 100vw;
      /* background-color:#000; */
    }
    
    .logo {
      position: absolute;
      width: 120px;
      height: 45px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: #E73A15;
      top: 30%;
      left: 2%;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      font-size: 2.5em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .social {
      position: absolute;
      top: 30%;
      left: 20%;
      width: 250px;
      height: 45px;
      /* background-color: black; */
    }
    
    ul {
      position: relative;
      top: 18%;
    }
    
    .social ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 12px 6px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .faceb,
    .linked,
    .git {
      position: relative;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #E73A15;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .centerIcon {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #menu {
      margin: 2.2rem 3rem 0 0;
      float: right;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    #menu ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: .5rem .8rem;
      margin: 0 .3rem;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: .7rem;
      font-weight: 900;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    #menu .nav a {
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .nav {
      background: rgb(209, 129, 129);
      background: linear-gradient(118deg, rgba(209, 129, 129, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 81, 52, 1) 35%, rgba(231, 58, 21, 1) 100%);
      border-radius: 50px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
      body {
        background: url(https://i.ibb.co/xhgZz0F/bg-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: auto;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
      }
      .social {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">Jury</div>
    <div class="social">
      <ul>
        <li class="faceb">
          <div class="centerIcon"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></div></i></li>
        <li class="linked">
          <div class="centerIcon"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></div></i></li>
        <li class="git">
          <div class="centerIcon"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </header>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi - @Jury  only change